# PHPStorm JSX/React syntax highlighting

Tags: phpstorm, reactjs

I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.3 for my current project, but unfortunately it doesn't support JSX. In my React components (which are then compiled by Browserify) HTML gets underlined in red and invalidated:

[image: PHPStorm React Template]

This is just a small component, but it surely gets pretty annoying with bigger ones. Also code formatting doesn't work as expected.

1. Is there a (hard to find) setting which enables the correct syntax highlighting?
2. If there is no such setting, is it possible to download a corresponding package?
3. If there is no support at all, how do I extend PHPStorm (maybe by a custom Color/Syntax Schema) to accept HTML within my js files?

Comment: Seems like WebStorm 9 and higher have built in JSX support - haven't seen a new version of PHPStorm, but maybe next version: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/10/webstorm-9-released-meteor-support-react-and-jsx-gulp-integration-and-more/

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Do I then have to switch windows when I take changes in my php and js files?

Comment: PhpStorm v9 will have it. You can grab latest EAP build if you want: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: @lenny.myr no, the JSX syntax is just supported by the editor window. If you were using an editor like Sublime, you'd be adding an ES6/JSX syntax and the editor would properly highlight your code. With PHP/Web Storm, you need to wait for Jetbrains to add the feature - or look around the internet, there are all kinds of hacks to add textmate-like syntaxes to the existing editor.

Comment: @LazyOne PhpStorm EAP works great for me.

Comment: PhpStorm 8, also supports JSX - you just need switch JavaScript Language version to JSX Harmory in settings. But it looks EAP has better jsx support, so I am using it.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem and solution is to either use JSX Harmony on PHPStorm 8:

`Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript`

set `JavaScript language version` to `JSX Harmony`

or move to PHPStorm 9 EAP. I hope PHPStorm 9 will be available soon, though (as I had performance issue with EAP version).

Comment: I did the same thing changing the language version to `JSX harmony` but it is not showing the react syntax..please help me with this

Comment: After changing `Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript` you might want to restart PHPStorm, I needed to.

Answer (score 8):

on **PHPStorm 7**:

File->setting->Languages & Frameworks->JavaScript->

*Select the option **React JSX** in the drop down list (JavaScript Language version*)

Comment: I already switch the Javascript language version to React JSX but the "syntax error" still shows up

Comment: In my case I had te `React Templates` plugin installed which was messing up the syntax highlighting

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to also click on the `...` beside the drop down and specify the directory that my project was in.

Comment: I do not have React JSX in the drop down list. How to make it appear in the drop down?

Answer (score -2):

**Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > JavaScript language version** Choose React JSX from dropdown and wait after progress bar is completed to apply changes.