# PhpStorm for React gives me a red underline

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I'm using PhpStorm 2018.1, and coding a ReactJS based project. I was a little annoyed with the red underline which seemed to say that my code was error even though it wasn't.

[image: Problem no.1]
[image: Problem no.2]

I have followed the answers given from this forum:

1. [WebStorm/PhpStorm warning for react attributes in jsx like className](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126292/webstorm-phpstorm-warning-for-react-attributes-in-jsx-like-classname)
2. [PHPStorm JSX/React syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309690/phpstorm-jsx-react-syntax-highlighting)

but this red underline still appears.

I installed a few plugins for JavaScript and ES6 debugging
[image]
[image]

The question is is there another PhpStorm plugin that I didn't install?

Comment: Well .. from what I see your 2nd screenshot clearly shows the reason -- configure your JSHint to reflect that ES6 version is used here. If you do not use/do not need JSHint ... then just disable that inspection (use search box in Settings/Preferences to quickly narrow the possible location).

Comment: @LazyOne If I disable JSHint, does that affect with my debugging the code? Is there any alternative debugger like this for React?

Comment: JSHint is a linter ... and has nothing to do with actually running or debugging your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are reported by JShint linter, not by PhpStorm itself.
You have to tell JSHint that you are using ES2015 syntax. This can be done by adding

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

comment to your file (http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion), or by specifying

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

in `.jshintrc` file. If you don't have your own config file, you can enable **EcmaScript.next** in **Relaxing** options in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint**

If you didn't mean to use JSHint for linting your React application (and I'd say that this linter is a bit outdated and doesn't work well for JSX + ES6), just disable it by unchecking **Enable** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint**

Comment: Thanks, some major "error" was fixed but it still has some error in other line. So I just disable it